XML Schema Validation Error in Add-in Manifest for Word Task Pane with Title Field
I'm developing a Word web add-in with a task pane and dialog using office-js. The task pane functionality works perfectly when I sideload the add-in locally.
Here’s the relevant part of my manifest where I use the Title field:
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <Title resid="Taskpane1.Title" />
    <TaskpaneId>Taskpane1</TaskpaneId>
    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane1.Url" />
</Action>

When I validate the manifest using the command:
npx office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml

I receive the following error:
Error #1: 
XML Schema Validation Error: Error found during XML Schema validation.
  - Details: The element 'Action' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides' has invalid child element 'Title' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'. List of possible elements expected: 'TaskpaneId, SourceLocation' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides'.
  - Line: 94
  - Column: 42

I referred to the Microsoft documentation, but I couldn't find clarity on why Title is causing an issue during validation.
Does anyone know the correct way to define the Title field in this context, or if there is an alternative approach to displaying a title for the task pane?
How can I resolve this schema validation issue?

Just a guess, really, but it Looks like a sequence problem, I.e. you need TaskPaneId, SourceLocation, Title in that order. You have to have a SourceLocation, but not necessarily a TaskPaneId, so the parser is presumably expecting one of those first.

It is a matter of order: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/manifest-element-ordering

Thank you jonsson and @RickKirkham for quick response.
